# How would you say "by virtue of"?

Tags: translation

Google translate gives me "en virto de".

If this is correct, could you please give me an example sentence in Esperanto?

Dankegon!

Comment: Does "by virtue of" mean something other than "because of" and "due to"?

Comment: Ĉu eblus aldoni tutan frazon al la demando? Kunteksto gravas.

Answer (score 2):

As Eduardo Trápani already implied single word requests without a context are often quite hard to answer, especially when it comes to idioms like this.

Virtue as such means behaviour showing high moral standards or an order of celestial hierarchy in Christian mythodology. The saying "by virtue of" was originally based on the former meaning. That there exist "a higher standard" that gives a king, a nobleman or some self-promoted person a right or a justification to do something. Later the expression has shifted to mean "because of" or "due to":

- She got the job by virtue of her greater experience. (Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)
- They were excluded from voting by virtue of being too young (Cambridge Dictionary)

The Esperanto word *virto* refers to that high moral standard. For more specific definitions and examples of use see [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#virto_kdc). The Esperanto word *virto* has nothing to do with a right or a justification. The preposition [*pro*](https://vortaro.net/#pro_kdc) is one possibility, but there are others depending on the context. Remember, translate ideas, not words.

So if I were to translate the examples above

- *Ŝi ricevis la postenon **danke al** sia granda sperto.*
- *Ilin oni ne allasis voti **pro** tro juna aĝo.*

Answer (score 1):

In English *by virtue of* signals a reason, that reason coming after *of* in the form of a noun phrase (similar to *because of*, *due to*, etc.).

A similar construction in Esperanto, introducing a noun phrase as a reason, would be *pro*.

**Pro** la multon da tempo, kiun ŝi  elspezis helpante al Roberto fariĝi virino, ŝi forgesis forigi la ungolakon. 
'**With** all the time she spent helping Robert become a woman, she forgot to take off her nail polish.'

Answer (score 0):

At:
https://eo.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aldono:Vortaro_angla-Esperanto_v
the examples under 'virtue' might be helpful.